# Stopping animations in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-animation

I am trying to make an animation in android studio that will start when I double click the screen. Since I am using a scroll view and that takes up the whole screen I used that as the view to detect the double tap.

I wanted 2 things to happen:

1. When ever I double tap the screen, the animation should start and stop. And
2. When I play with the volume rockers it will speed up the animation, even if the animation already started.

So far here is my code for the double tap method:

```
private void doubleTapToScroll() {
    findViewById(R.id.minchaScroll).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        //  while(mScrollView.getScrollY() <= findViewById(R.id.alenuPart3).getBottom()){
                        //      audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                        //      int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                        //      ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mScrollView, "scrollY", (findViewById(R.id.minchaLinearLayout)).getBottom()).setDuration(currentVolume*100000).start();
                        //  }
                        audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                        int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mScrollView, "scrollY", (findViewById(R.id.minchaLinearLayout)).getBottom()).setDuration(currentVolume * 10000);

                        autoScrollOn = !autoScrollOn;

                        if (animator.isRunning()) {
                            animator.start();
                        } else {
                            animator.cancel();
                        }

                        Log.d("In Run Method", String.valueOf(autoScrollOn));
                    }
                });
                return super.onDoubleTap(e);
            }
        });
```

I am working on part 1 for now, for some reason the animation will not pause.

Also for part 2, I already take in the volume level and if I change it before the animation starts it works at different speeds, I am in the process of trying to make the speed change while the animation is on with a while loop and restarting the animation, but I don't think that would be the ideal way, any ideas?

Thanks!

Update: I tried, `.pause, .end and mScrollView.clearAnimation();` (not sure if that is even a good thought)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

It was because in the line of :

```
 ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mScrollView, "scrollY", (findViewById(R.id.minchaLinearLayout)).getBottom()).setDuration(currentVolume * 10000);
```

I was creating a `new animator object` every single double click, so when I went to pause the animator on the second double click. I was creating a new animator object and pauseing that one.

I fixed it by making a `boolean` of `firstDoubleClick` and then making it `false` right there after. The next time around, it didn't make a `new object` rather `paused` the old one.